# sqliteDatabase.delete implementation

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

How do I "translate" the following SQL statement for using `sqliteDatabase.delete(...)` -

```
DELETE FROM EVENTS_TB WHERE event_time < some_time
```

Where `event_time` and `some_time` are long and `some_time` is calculated time according to user's selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `delete()` method of `SQLiteDatabase` instance.

```
sq.delete("<tablename>", "event_time < ?", new String {String.valueOf(some_time)});
```

or cleaner is when you declared db columns like `static final` fields for example

```
static final String KEY_EVENT_TIME = "event_time";
static final String TABLE_NAME = "EVENTS_TB";

sq.delete(TABLE_NAME , KEY_EVENT_TIME + " < ?", new String {String.valueOf(some_time)});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here they are. it will work

```
public void deleteAdById(int some_time) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    final String whereClause = event_time  + "<?";
    final String[] whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(some_time) };
    db.delete(EVENTS_TB, whereClause, whereArgs);
    db.close();
}
```